# only default permalinks working wordpress others become 404 error

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My problem is in my wordpress site only default permalinks is working.. When I change permalinks all pages become not found.. only home page is showing.

When I change permalinks to postname .htaccess content change to

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

And for default it is

```
# BEGIN WordPress

# END WordPress
```

Also tried to get the status of mod_rewrite using this

```
in_array( 'mod_rewrite', apache_get_modules())
```

It returns 1 and mod_rewrite is enabled on my server and also checked using phpinfo(). `mod_rewrite` module is loaded.. I have gone through all the documents available in internet.. Please help me to solve this problem.. My hosting server is godaddy..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In case you are on Ubuntu, edit the file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf (here we have an example of /var/www):

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and change it to:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

also check Apache configuration file for your website /etc/apache2/sites-available/your_site.conf:

```
<Directory /var/www/your_site_path/>
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

and change it to:

```
<Directory /var/www/your_site_path/>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

You need to do sudo a2enmod rewrite to enable module rewrite

then,

sudo service apache2 restart

***I hope this helps you!***

Comment: tried but not working for me..

Comment: /etc/apache2/sites-available/ i have only two file 000-default.conf  default-ssl.conf which one i have to open it?

Answer (score 8):

It could be a broken `rewrite_rules` field in your database.

I installed "Yoast SEO" into a live site and that broke it completely. I disabled the plugin but it didn't go back to working. Only default permalinks would work.

Like everyone else I tried the usual things - checking `.htaccess`, making sure that `mod_rewrite` was working on the server, saving the permalinks settings again, but nothing was working. The homepage would load, and `wp-admin` pages would load, but everything else was just loading the "Latest Posts" default page.

In the end it turned out to be something wrong with the `rewrite_rules` field of `wp_options` in the database.

I had three versions of the site (local, staging and production), and all were from one SVN base, so I knew it was not a file issue. But only the local development version was working.

I replaced the contents of the `rewrite_rules` field of the broken live site with the working  one from my local development site, and it worked.

What's really weird is that deleting the `rewrite_rules` field and having WordPress rebuild it did not fix the problem. Only replacing with the contents of a previously working version of the site did the trick.

I'm still puzzled by this, and will edit this reply if I find out anything further about the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same issue and fixed it by running

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Then restarted apache. Apparently the issue is caused by `mod_rewrite` potentially not working properly on ubuntu.

I found the solution [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/changing-away-from-plain-permalinks-just-plain-doesnt-work/)

Comment: I installed WP with "AllowOverride None" and "modRewrite disabled", 
that was default conf in fresh ubuntu install on aws

Solved putting 
AllowOverride All in the website directory config,
and sudo a2enmod rewrite as you say

Thanks

Comment: It's working for me. Thank you.. upvote from my side.

Answer (score 3):

suffered from the same issue. Having site on SSL had to change NOT the 000-default.conf but the respective SSL conf file. Adding

after DocumentRoot /var/www/html

```
the following

<Directory "/var/www/html">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

and then restarting apache2 saved my site.... nothing else worked. The issue was Wordpress SSL and SEO plugins messing up config files.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue in Wordpress installed on CentOS7 and the solution was to edit httpd.conf file with this command:

```
sudo vi /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

And replace

```
<Directory "/var/www/wordpress">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride none
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

with

```
<Directory "/var/www/wordpress">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

then restart Apache:

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd.service
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is too late. i faced the same issue and solved by changing

```
AllowOverride None
```

to

```
AllowOverride All
```

in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-deafult.conf file. hope this would help.

Comment: In 000-deafult.conf file i didn't found neither AllowOverride None nor AllowOverride All

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same challenge after setting up WordPress on Ubuntu 22 and configuring an SSL certificate for the site.
This is how I was able to resolve it.

Open the apache config file for editing (using nano in this case)

```
 sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Change the following line:

```
<Directory "/var/www">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride none
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to:

```
<Directory "/var/www">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Open the default SSL config file for editing

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf
```

Add the following code:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

Restart Apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

You should now be able to change the site permalink structure without seeing the 404 page not found error.