# Wordpress permalinks does not work on server

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have uploaded WordPress website to a new server which is working fine. But Permalinks settings are not working. All other pages returning me 404 error.

and below in my `.htacces`s file

```
    
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: What is your permalink structure?

Comment: try this: go to the permalink setting set it to default and save it, and aging change it to the needed one.

Comment: What WebServer used? Does webserver environment allow url rewriting (mod_rewrite for Apache, of try block for nginx)?

Comment: [Maybe you can find a solution here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54791785/7600833)

Answer (score 2):

please check the apache module rewrite.

in a root wordpress folder insert into index.php phpinfo();
and find this string mod_rewrite. If it`s not, tell it your hoster support

Comment: Nobody said a word about Apache =), but most probably thsi is a case!

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error one can also try this method:

Open **phpmyadmin** > **wordpress database** >  **wp_options table**

Here check first two fields and update **option_value** with correct WordPress location. After that reload the permalink, hopefully the error might gone

Answer (score 0):

Go to "wp-admin", open **settings->permalinks** and update the permalink settings, it will update the .htaccess file on your server. Hard refresh your site, now all the links will be work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

there's a one tiny trick to update all links if you can access admin .

you just go to permalinks options from settings page and save permalinks to default and after saving it you may change again and update. This will work in most cases for me either its SSL based issue or urls mismatch. don't forget to view .htaccess file if you have old server and having multiple rewrites.